# Cannot set GeoIP rules in iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, rules, geoip

I try to add this rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m geoip ! --src-cc CZ,SK -j DROP
```

I set GeoIP support according to this answer: [Ubuntu IPTables allow only allow 1 country | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/996526/ubuntu-iptables-allow-only-allow-1-country)

But it doesn't work, because I get message: iptables: `No chain/target/match by that name.`

I use Debian 9.

**Update:**

After result after running `uname -a`

```
Linux Andromeda 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked Q/A is incomplete. In addition to userland tools, you need the kernel side equivalent: you'll have to install the package [`xtables-addons-dkms`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xtables-addons-dkms). Note that [`xtables-addons-common`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xtables-addons-common) *recommends* `xtables-addons-dkms`, so installing the former should have either installed the later, or mentioned the recommendation. Not doing it severely limits the usefulness of `xtables-addons-common`.

Beware, it will pull a whole compilation suite needed by [`dkms`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/dkms). Make sure you get the [`linux-headers-4.9.0-4-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-headers-4.9.0-4-amd64) package because it's not the latest available and might not be pulled automatically.

If that's understandably not acceptable for production systems, it will have to be installed on a development system and this will have to be run manually. The exact command might depend on the target kernel's version:

```
dkms mkbmdeb xtables-addons/2.12 -k 4.9.0-4-amd64
```

The newly built package found with:

```
find /var/lib/dkms/ -name 'xtables-addons*deb'
```

can then be installed on the production server (along with the [`xtables-addons-common`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xtables-addons-common) package).

To state it again: `dkms mkbmdeb ...` is needed only for a "two stages" installation. If `xtables-addons-dkms` is installed directly on the server using the iptables rules, it doesn't have to be done: the installation took care of it already.

Comment: Why should I build it? I already installed package "xtables-addons-common" via "apt install xtables-addons-common", do you mean this package https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-i386/xtables-addons-source_2.12-0.1_all.deb.html ?

Comment: Can you edit the question and add your kernel version  and architecture (eg: `uname -a`) I'll update my answer in case it's not amd64

Comment: Updated, so it is required to run "dkms mkbmdeb xtables-addons/2.12 -k 4.9.0-6-amd64"? Because I didn't find this in any geoip tutorials.

Comment: That's why I added the debian tag: it's a Debian problem more than any geoip tutorial. mkbmdeb is needed only if you don't install *directly* xtables-addons-dkms to the target server. It's not needed (and might even clash) if you install it (with gcc etc.) on the server having the iptables rules

Comment: I understand that I have to make "two stage" installation because of Debian now.. And how can be "xtables-addons-dkms" installed directly on the server using the iptables rules? Sorry for dumb question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76068/discussion-between-a-b-and-tomsk).